# How to sort words in a column in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have data as

```
id action
1  a
1  b
2  b
2  a
3  c
```

I wrote code as

```
select id,group_concat(action SEPARATOR ' ')
from table1;
```

It ends up as

```
id action
1  a b
2  b a
3  c
```

Actually, ba and ab is the same one, how could we sort it?

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` accepts `ORDER BY` inside,`...group_concat(action ORDER BY action SEPARATOR ' ')`

Comment: @Mihai since you have the right concept please write your comment as a full answer so we can upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GROUP_CONCAT accepts ORDER BY ,so your query becomes

```
select id,group_concat(action ORDER BY action SEPARATOR ' ') from table1;
```